# how to extract only content from dropbox without downloading files from dropbox

Tags: java, dropbox

I just try to extract content from dropbox files without download files from dropbox.please give any idea for how to extract content from dropbox files without download that.I used dropbox-core-sdk api.

Comment: Don't you have access to the `OutputStream` that is been used to write the content...You could pipe just about anywhere you want...

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to use [`startGetFile()`](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#startGetFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). E.g.:

```
InputStream in = dbxClient.startGetFile("myfile.txt", null).body;
// read from the input stream
```